# Return function Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I have an issue with a asynchronous function. I've a service that provides me some data from a firebase database. One of those function returns a value:

```
historialDeConsumi() {
    this.item = this.af.database.object('/users/' + this.uid + '/admin', {
      preserveSnapshot: true
    });
    this.item.subscribe(snapshot => {
       this.hijosHistorialConsumi = snapshot.child('HisotialCons').val();

    });
    return this.hijosHistorialConsumi;
}
```

I call this function from a component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.consumi = this.servicioData.historialDeConsumi();
}
```

I want to match `this.consumi` to a value returned by function. I don't know the way to do this.

Comment: return `promise` or ` observable` from the function and do `then` or `subscribe` in your `ngOnInit()`

Comment: You don't need to take snapshots, or subscribe, or store the data somewhere. The data is already there in the observable. Just subscribe to it as an object where you need it, or better yet, directly in a template using an async pipe.

Comment: @BhavikPatel It's **already** an observable.

Comment: Added [firebase] and [angularfire2] tags

Comment: @torazaburo - the point was to return an `observable` instead of a variable/object

Comment: @BhavikPatel - the point is that `this.af.database.object` already returns an observable.

Answer (score 4):

Your code won't work, of course, since you are trying to return something which doesn't exist yet. The most straightforward approach (but not the best, by any means) is to store the unwrapped observable in a service variable, then provide a way to retrieve it. In the below, I am using simplified/sample data:

```
// Keep data locally.
private data;

// Listen to observable in constructor, and store locally.
constructor() {
    this.item = this.af.database.object(path, {
      preserveSnapshot: true
    });
    this.item.subscribe(snapshot => {
       this.data = snapshot.val();
    });
}      

// Retrieve the data.
getData() { return this.data; }
```

Note, however, that the entire idea of using snapshots is unnecessary. AngularFire returns observables which can be directly subscribed to. Therefore:

```
constructor() {
    this.item = this.af.database.object(path);
    this.item.subscribe(data => this.data = data);
}
```

or more simply, just

```
constructor() {
    this.af.database.object(path).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
}
```

However, this approach has a serious flaw. Whoever calls the accessor will get the **latest** value, but while they are holding onto that, if a new value arrives, they will never know about it, and will be left using the old one. Or, if someone calls the accessor before the observable has fired for the first time, which is entirely possible, they will end up getting `undefined`, with no way to then retrieve subsequent values.

Therefore, the service should simply return the observable, and the component would consume it.

```
// SERVICE
getData() { return this.af.database.object(path); }

// COMPONENT
public data;

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getData().subscribe(data => this.data = data);
}

<div>The data is {{data}}</div>
```

In other words, we "unwrap" the observable in `ngOnInit`, and store its unwrapped value locally. This will sort of work like you want. However, the initial value of `data` will be undefined, until the observable emits its first value, so if you are trying to access a property on the data, assuming it's an object:

```
<div>The name is {{data.name}}</div>
```

You will get an error trying to access the `name` property on `undefined`. The most obvious way to deal with that is to use the `?` operator, as in

```
<div> The name is {{data?.name}}</div>
```

However, you may not want to have to do that everywhere in your template, and remember that AOT does not support the `?`. The unpleasant alternative is to wrap this in `<div *ngIf="data">` everywhere.

Therefore, the preferred approach is to leave the observable as an observable until the last moment and unwrap it (subscribe to it) only when necessary, which you can do as follows (using the convention of naming variables holding observables with a final `$` for clarity):

```
// COMPONENT
public data$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.data$ = this.service.getData();
}

<div>The data is {{data$ | async}}</div>
```

using the `async` pipe, which subscribes implicitly. If you want to retrieve a property on `data`, then

```
<div>The name is {{(data$ | async).name}}</div>
```

and everything will work as expected. If you want to handle the case where the observable has not emitted yet, then

```
The name is
  <div *ngIf="data$ | async as data"; else loading">{{data.name}}</div>
  <ng-template #loading>not loaded yet</ng-template>
```

If you want to somehow pre-process or manipulate the value of the observable, instead of unwrapping it either in the service or the component, and then performing the manipulation on the unwrapped value, manipulate the observable itself using `map`:

```
public firstName$;

ngOnInit() {
  this.firstName$ = this.service.getData().map(data => data.name.split(' ')[0]);
}
```

Then consume that mapped observable in your template as

```
The first name is
  <div *ngIf="firstName$ | async as firstName"; else loading">{{firstName}}</div>
  <ng-template #loading>not loaded yet</ng-template>
```

In summary, the preferred pattern for working with AngularFire observables, and indeed all observables, is to leave them as observables for as long as possible, manipulate them by mapping (or filtering) them into new observables, avoid unwrapping them and storing their values locally if at all possible, and finally subscribe at the point where the value is actually needed, which is quite often in the template, where the subscription can be handled by the `async` pipe.

Using the `async` pipe has another major advantage. If you subscribe explicitly in the component logic, you will have to remember that subscription, and then unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy` to avoid memory leaks. In contrast, Angular automatically cleans up any subscriptions done implicitly using the `async` pipe for you.

Comment: Very nice answer! I remember I ran into some trouble with subscribing to observables in the constructor resp. OnInit when writing tests, too. It is really hard to mock or overwrite the subscription then.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read up about how `RXJS Observables` work: [RXJS Doc](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/)

Basically what you want to do is to subscribe on your `Observable` from your `component`. Your service should just return (or maybe manipulate the incoming data before returning) it.

This could look something like this:

```
myServiceFun(): Observable<any> {
    return doMyRequest().map((response: any) => {
          // manipulate it maybe here
          return response;
    });
}
```

In your component you subscribe to this `Observable`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.backendService.myServiceFunc().subscribe((response: any) => {
         this.myComponentProp = response;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `await` and `async` to simplify the code:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

async historialDeConsumi(){
    let item = this.af.database.object('/users/' + this.uid + '/admin', { preserveSnapshot: true });
    let snapshot = await item.toPromise();
    return snapshot.child('HisotialCons').val();
}

async ngOnInit() {
    this.consumi = await this.servicioData.historialDeConsumi();
}
```

This way the code looks very much closer to how it would be if the database query was just an ordinary function call. Use `toPromise()` to convert an `Observable` into a `Promise`. Turn the methods into `async` methods and that lets you use `await` to wait for completion of any promise, it also means any value you return from the method will be wrapped into a promise, so the caller has to use `await` or treat it like a promise and call `.then()` on it.

Do remember that although it makes the code read like synchronous code everything is still happening asynchronously so the value won't be set until the asynchronous part completes. However as angular already knows how to handle an asynchronous `ngOnInit()` that shouldn't be a problem, it will wait for the result.

Comment: This is of course another option, but imho i don't see the benefits in using Promises. Of course rxjs provides this option, but we use Observables for a reason and not promises anymore. I dont think it's a good thing to promote it.

Comment: @lexith, both observables and promises have their place. In this situation using the promise allows a style of laying out the code which is much closer to the synchronous form and therefore I think is the better choice here.

Comment: @lexith for single valued streams, aka most XHRs, promises honestly make more sense. Even the creator of Rx, Erik Meijer, has stated that Tasks/Promises are the correct abstractions for single asynchronously delivered values. The code clarity and simplicity, of `async`/`await` are really beneficial in CRUD apps. Sure, sometimes you need an autocomplete or polling, or cross-web-service calls in which case RxJS is perfect, but pick the right tool for the job.

Comment: This fails to take advantage of the nature of the AngularFire interface, whose entire purpose in life is to give you back observables that you can use as is without snapshotting, awaiting, or dereferencing.

Comment: @torazaburo that is definitely true. I did not notice the actually service `this.af.database` in use, I just saw a run of the mill async issue. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @torazaburo doesn't that imply that the OP should be using an entirely different pattern though? Like using a multi-cast subject or something?